# Multiple Charts On One Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

i have created a javascript chart to use on my project dashboard however i am struggling to make it work with multiple charts and the same ID (they have to be the same names as they will be inside a PHP for each loop).

As you can see in this pen:

http://codepen.io/assasinate66/pen/GrMBYp

```
                <div class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="40"><!--Pie Chart -->
                <div class="ppc-progress">
                    <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ppc-percents">
                <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
                    <span>%</span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--End Chart -->

            <div class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="70"><!--Pie Chart -->
                <div class="ppc-progress">
                    <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ppc-percents">
                <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
                    <span>%</span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--End Chart -->
<script>
 $(function(){
  var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart'),
    percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent')),
    deg = 360*percent/100;
  if (percent > 50) {
    $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
  }
  $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
  $('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
});
  </script>
```

i have defined the different percentages but it is only displaying the first percentage on both charts, it seems like it needs a JS / Jquery loop of some sort.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting two elements at once and trying to set the properties of those elements. That's not going to work. The best way to fix this in my opinion is using a .each() (loop).

```
$(function(){
    var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart');
    $ppc.each(function(){
        var percent = parseInt($(this).data('percent'));
        var deg = 360*percent/100;
        if (percent > 50) {
            $(this).addClass('gt-50');
        }

        $(this).find('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
        $(this).find('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
      });
});
```

Use this JS and it will work like a charm!

Comment: Glad that I could be of help :) If it was the correct answer, please accept it as the answer.